# why my django template cant show the current thing 

Tags: python, django, templates

this is my views.py :

```
a=['aaa','bbb','oooo','qqqq','gggg']

def main(request, template_name='index.html'):
    context ={
              'n':range(len(a)),
              'a':a,
    }
    return render_to_response(template_name, context)
```

this is my html :

```
{% for i in n %}

    {{a.i}} ww {{a.i+1}}

{% endfor %}
```

it show `ww ww ww ww ww`  ,

but  i want to show `'aaawwbbb bbbwwoooo oooowwqqqq qqqqwwgggg ggggww'`

so  what can i do ,

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom filter, http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-template-tags/ and have something like this:

```
# myfilters.py
def return_element(list, index):
    return list[index+1]
```

And then you can use it from the template,

```
{% include myfilters %}
...
{% for i in a %}
    {{ i }}ww{{ a|return_element:forloop.counter0 }}
{% endfor %}
```

The forloop template variable is automatically set within a for tag.. forloop.counter0 returns the number of times loop is entered, and uses zero-indexing.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> c=Context({'a':['aaa', 'bbb', 'oooo', 'qqqq', 'gggg']})
>>> Template("{% for x in a %}{% if not forloop.first %}{{ x }} {% endif %}{{ x }}ww{% endfor %}").render(c)
u'aaawwbbb bbbwwoooo oooowwqqqq qqqqwwgggg ggggww'
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. Iterate on list directly.

```
context = {
    'a': a
}
return render_to_response(template_name, context)
```

And in template:

```
{% for x in a %}
    {{ x }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You might want to make it {{ x }}ww as per the OPs original requirement :)

Comment: @zjm: Then pass a different list to the template. Or explain what you're actually doing better.